# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment

Tags: java, android

When I was using targetSdkVersion 26 my code was running fine now I have changed my targetSdkVersion as 28 so now I am getting these crashes on some devices of android version 8.0+ What I do now...???

I have changed UrduSimplePreferenceFragment from protected to the public but am still getting same crashes

e8.java

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content,
                        new UrduSimplePreferenceFragment()).commit();

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    }
    @SuppressLint("validFragment")
    public class  UrduSimplePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.z4);
            Log.e("kk", "onCreate");
            InterstitialAdmob();


            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            Preference pref = findPreference("changetheme");
            pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    themesDialog();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            /*if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }*/

        }

    }
```

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage/com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage.e8}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage.e8.UrduSimplePreferenceFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage.e8.UrduSimplePreferenceFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:429)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:470)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:462)
    at com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage.e8.onCreate(e8.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is not clear in `Fragment com.multi.keyboard.khmer.keyboard.khmerlanguage.e8.UrduSimplePreferenceFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:429)`?

Comment: it says `public class UrduSimplePreferenceFragment` should be `public static class UrduSimplePreferenceFragment`

Answer (score 0):

```
UrduSimplePreferenceFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
```

Make UrduSimplePreferenceFragment a public static class

```
public static class UrduSimplePreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.z4);
        Log.e("kk", "onCreate");
        InterstitialAdmob();


        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        Preference pref = findPreference("changetheme");
        pref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                themesDialog();
                return true;
            }
        });
        /*if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }*/

    }

}
```

Comment: I have do the same as you suggest but then i get some errors which says
Non-static method 'InterstitialAdmob();' cannot be Referenced from static contect
Non-static method 'getActionBar()' cannot be Referenced from static contect

Comment: Why are you calling these functions in Preference class? Why don't you call them in the onCreate of Activity class ?